# How can I implement ChangeStreams for MongoDB in Spring Boot Application (Kotlin) and then send message to rabbitmq broker?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, rabbitmq, changestream

I want to implement ChangeStreams for my mongodb.
I'm using Spring Boot and Kotlin.
My mongodb contains one database with a collection where i store vehicle data.
I would like to observe if any changes occur in my collection and if so, send a message to rabbitmq (message should contain two fields of my collection: id and market).
Could anynone help me please?

```
 @Bean
fun main() {
    log.info { "another ChangeStream function is listening" }
    val uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017"

    val mongoClient = MongoClients.create(uri)
    mongoClient.use { client ->
        val database: MongoDatabase = client.getDatabase("test")
        val collection: MongoCollection<Document> = database.getCollection("vehicles")

        val pipeline: List<Bson> = listOf(
            Aggregates.match(
                Filters.`in`("operationType", listOf("insert", "update", "delete", "create"))
            )
        )

        val changeStream: ChangeStreamIterable<Document> = collection.watch(pipeline)
            .fullDocument(FullDocument.UPDATE_LOOKUP)

        // variables referenced in a lambda must be final; final array gives us a mutable integer
        val numberOfEvents = intArrayOf(0)
        changeStream.forEach { event ->
            println("Received a change to the collection: $event")
            if (++numberOfEvents[0] >= 2) {
                System.exit(0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**error message:**

```
 Type mismatch.
Required:
ChangeStreamIterable<Document>
Found:
ChangeStreamPublisher<Document!>
```

Comment: Looks like you are using the Reactive version of Mongo and not the regular version. Hence you need the publisher and not the iterator. As you state you are using Spring Boot there should be no need to create the client yourself, you should just inject that.

Comment: how can i inject? mongodb is defined in docker-compose.yml

Comment: but when i change any vehicle in the collection nothing is printed

Comment: Why would it matter that it is in a docker-compose file? Spring BOot doesn't care it will just create the client. It doesn't print anything because you get an error due to the wrong type being used. Fix that. ANd as it is reactive doing a foreach probably won't work. Also do you really want to do `System.exit` in that code to shutdown your app?

Comment: ok, thanks for the hints. but how can i inject MongoClients in this case?

Comment: Just as you would inject it in other beans. Your code is weird though, why is there an  `@Bean` on a `main` method in the first place? Your tags indicate Spring Boot usage but what you show here tries very hard to work around all that.

Comment: ok, could you send me your proposal please? i'm a newbie to change streams.